# Best method for multiple sites running off shared Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm developing the online presence of a new sporting league. The web presence will consist of the organisation's information site (think the NFL website) and then individual team sites.

My idea to achieve this was to pick a framework like Zend Framework, and then have two applications (main site and team sites application). When a visitor accesses the organisation's domain the request is handled by the organisation's application code, and when an attempt to access any of the teams' domains (they could be dozens) the request is sent to the team sites application code, and the skin is switched depending on the domain accessed via.

The reason I want all team sites to run from the same application code is, if I added a section (for example, roster) then I'll want that on *all* team sites. There's seldom going to be an occasion where a team is going to need an individual page, but I'll handle that when I come to develop the CMS.

What I need is just a helping hand on how the above scenario would work with Zend Framework. I have one Zend Framework library that I'd like to use for both applications (which is in my `include_path`) so would just like to know how the requests would be routed and the framework would be set up to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I should also mention that I'd like the share the models between the two applications. For example, the individual teams sites may feature profiles of players for that particular team, but the organisation site may offer profiles of *every* player.

Comment: The library is one part, your application code the other. You can share the library with both apps (or even more apps) by sharing the library folder via the include path. -- see: http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-general-discussions-1/concepts-ideas-planning-39/multiple-websites-one-shared-framework-193.html

Comment: I thought about just creating two different applications, but how would I go about sharing models between the two as detailed in my question edit above?

Comment: Probably create your own library of models. give it a name, place it in a folder, and do like you did for the zend framework library. It's just sharing code.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the ZF libs into the include path is basically all you need to do to share ZF between applications. You can share any models the same way. By putting them on the include path.

What you describe above doesnt sound like it needs multiple applications though. If all that varies is the site theme, then you can serve that all from the main application. Add a custom route that can detect when its a team site. For instance, when team sites are available at their own domain, map the domain name to the theme folder and apply any necessary filters to limit the player profiles.

An alternative would be to make the main application a consumable webservice. The other applications could then use the main application's API to fetch the appropriate player profiles.

Comment: The organisation site, and all the team sites will be fairly different. Think of it as tiers: the organisations oversees all the teams; and all of the teams are on the same level underneath. Although the API sounds like a good idea if the organisation site contains the models, and then has an API to expose this information to the team sites.